# Is it a clean way to create an errors folder to use throughout the program?

Tags: go

I'm making a small rest api for training.

Let's say I make a `useRepository` and want to return an error to the service meaning that the lines were not found.

```
func (u *userStorage) Find(ctx context.Context, userId int) (string, error) {
    sql := `SELECT user_name FROM user user_id = $1`
    var userName string
    err := u.client.QueryRow(ctx, sql, userId).Scan(&userName)
    if err != nil {
        if errors.Is(err, pgx.ErrNoRows) {
            return "", errs.ErrUserNotFound
        }
        return "", err
    }
    return userName, nil
}
```

To do this, I created the errs folder in internal package.

```
package errs

import "errors"

var (
    ErrUserNotFound error = errors.New("user cannot be found")
    ...
)
```

And now I can use this error in the service layer or inside handler

*handler.go*

```
...

if errors.Is(err, errs.ErrUserNotFound) 
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
...
```

And actually the question is is it a good practice to handle errors in several layers of the program like that , or is there a way to do it more correctly ?

Comment: You should put errors where they belong. Some general errors may be collected, such as `io.EOF`, but other than that do not do it. Also consider not using sentinel errors at all: [Dave Cheney: Don’t just check errors, handle them gracefully](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/04/27/dont-just-check-errors-handle-them-gracefully)

Comment: @icza Thanks for the reply.But then i have to check for example ```pgx.ErrNoRows``` inside handler.Is it right that handler should know about psql errors?

Comment: You can provide helper functions such as `func IsNoRecords(err error) bool` which hide / deal with implementation details.

Comment: I assume that your goal is make a distinction between a bad request an an internal server error. This is all a matter of opinion, but user not found error is specific enough that it should be declared with the API called by the handler.  If the handler calls userStorage.Find directly, then the error should be declared with the userStorage type.  Because userStorage is not exported, it looks like the handler calls an interface.  In that case, declare the error with interface.